# Applications not seeing NoMachine pulseaudio microphone source

Tags: webrtc, slack, pulseaudio, audacity, nomachine

I'm remoted into a Linux VM running CentOS 7 via NoMachine. NoMachine presents the client's microphone as a pulseaudio source. I can use Audacity to record from the pulseaudio source.
However, other applications - Chrome, Firefox, Slack, WebEx - don't see or don't recognize the pulseaudio source as a microphone.
test.webrtc.org says `[ FAILED ] Failed to get access to local media due to error: NotFoundError`.

`pacmd list-sources` shows:

`2 source(s) available.
    index: 1
    name: <nx_voice_out.monitor>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
  * index: 2
    name: <nx_audio_in.monitor>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>`

How do I get applications to recognize the pulseaudio source as a microphone?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by remapping the source:

`pacmd load-module module-remap-source master=nx_voice_out.monitor source_name=Microphone`

I don't know why this works, since all I've done is to essentially rename the source. I've not remapped any properties of the original source. Perhaps applications do not like the `.monitor` in the name of the original source.

I also needed to unload the suspend on idle module:

`pacmd unload-module module-suspend-on-idle`

Otherwise pulseaudio sometimes suspends the remapped source and I'm unable to unsuspednd it.